# converting List<String> to Object

Tags: java

In my current project,  I want  to convert  `List<String>` to  `RegionLabel` Object.

For  instance,  User enters String value one by one in order -- `center`, `floor`, `room` . I am storing user's input into List.

Now, my internal data structure in  `RegionLabel( String centerString, String floorString, String roomString);`

My requirement is to convert `List<String>` data structure into `RegionLabel("center", floor", "room" );` data structure.

One note:
My RegionLabel class  is generated  on-fly. On-fly means at design time, I do not know that  "how many arguments RegionLabel constructors have?"

-Pankesh

Comment: Is `RegionLabel(String, String, String)` a constructor?

Comment: Too many unknowns in this scenario. You don't know the number of arguments beforehand, so you can't map by index. You don't know the names of the properties, so you can't map by name/reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new constructor like `RegionLabel(List<String> list)`. This should do.

```
public RegionLabel(List<String> list) throws Exception{
     if( null == list || list.size() < 3 )
          throw new Exception("illegal parameter");
     this.centre = list.get(0);
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you're just after

```
new RegionLabel(list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2))
```

> I do not know that "how many arguments RegionLabel constructors have?"

Then you'll have to use reflection, or provide a constructor that accepts a `List<String>` as argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegionLabel label = new RegionLabel(inputList.get(0), inputList.get(1), inputList.get(2));
```

Simplified without any errorhandling or validation but without any more constraints on your "conversion", it's hard to be more generic.